# Is it true for any associative groupoid which elements are $a,b,c$, that $(a\ \circ \ b) \circ c = (b \ \circ c) \circ a $?

Tags: abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics

As I know an associative groupoid is a semigroup. I'm assuming that it can be true, but I'm not sure, how can I give a proof for it?

Comment: My guess would be no because we at least know that $(a \circ b) \circ c = a \circ (b \circ c)$ by associativity, but to have that be equal to $(b \circ c) \circ a$ would I think require commutativity.  Not posting an answer, though, because I don't know enough about groupoids.

Comment: I know that a groupid is idempotent,associative,commutative,has zero and identity element and it also has an inverse. Should I maybe make a proof with these properties?

Comment: Groupoids are commutative?  I can't find a resource that says that's true in general.  But if you have commutativity then I think that's all you need after using associativity.

Comment: I think you are mixing up two things called groupoids. A groupoid used to be a weaker version of a group (I forgot precisely which of the properties are part of it). In most modern texts, a groupoid is a (possibly small) category all of whose morphisms are invertible.

Comment: It's really not true in general, that a groupoid is commuatative...

Comment: But in this case there has to be a counter example, at least I think so, to show that it's not true

Comment: Do I read correctly that the grouped in question has _only_ $a,b,c$?

Comment: Following the [*algebraic* definition of groupoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groupoid#Algebraic) (essentially like group, but $\circ$ is a partial function), would it even follow that if $a\circ b$ and $b\circ c$ are defined, then $(b\circ c)\circ a$ is defined?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen it seems that the OP talks about associative [magmas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magma_(algebra)) (also known as semigroups). The term groupoid can also be used to refer to a magma, but it's not to be confused with the groupoid from category theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $G = (\{a,b,c\},\circ)$ be the groupoid where $\circ$ obeys the following table:

$$
\begin{array}{c|ccc} \circ & a & b & c \\ \hline a & a & a & a \\ b & b & b & b \\ c & a & a & c \end{array}
$$

One can check that $\circ$ is an associative operation. However

$$(a\circ b)\circ c = a \circ c = a \neq b = b\circ a = (b\circ c)\circ a.$$

My code found $7$ such groupoids (that is, up to isomorphism). Other than the one above, these are:

$$
\begin{array}{lcccr}
\begin{array}{c|ccc} \circ & a & b & c \\ \hline a & a & a & a \\ b & b & b & b \\ c & b & b & b \end{array} & &
\begin{array}{c|ccc} \circ & a & b & c \\ \hline a & a & a & a \\ b & b & b & b \\ c & c & c & c \end{array} & &
\begin{array}{c|ccc} \circ & a & b & c \\ \hline a & a & a & c \\ b & a & b & c \\ c & a & a & c \end{array} \\ \\
\begin{array}{c|ccc} \circ & a & b & c \\ \hline a & a & b & a \\ b & a & b & b \\ c & a & b & c \end{array} & &
\begin{array}{c|ccc} \circ & a & b & c \\ \hline a & a & c & c \\ b & a & b & c \\ c & a & c & c \end{array} & &
\begin{array}{c|ccc} \circ & a & b & c \\ \hline a & b & b & c \\ b & b & b & c \\ c & b & b & c \end{array} 
\end{array}
$$

If my code is correct this are the only $3$-element associative groupoids (up to isomorphism) that don't satisfy the identity in the stated problem.